# deploy each function in a separate Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions

my project has 3 Service bus and 2 HTTP triggers. (5 functions)

How to deploy each function in a separate Azure function app?

Comment: Other question: why would you? Anyway, how about creating 5 different solutions?

Comment: Maybe you can create five different solutions, and then deploy them to each function app individually.

Comment: Function app should correspond to the project on local. You can have a look at my answer.

Comment: Hi, do you have other doubts? If not, can you [mark the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2eE3.jpg) to end this question? Thanks.:)

Answer (score 2):

**The easiest way is to copy the code of the trigger you created before and create a new function app with a single trigger,** then put the code into it(Deploy function app must be based on function app, and the function app should correspond to the project on local.).

**The more complicated method is, first make sure the structure of your function app**(this needs to check the language. function app has two types, one type is a scripting language and another type needs to be compiled.) For this, you can have a check of this official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages

Go to the language you are using and search the folder structure(your deployment structure should like the 'folder structure' in the doc. What needs to pay attention to is for the language like C# and java, you need to deploy the compiled files. Azure can't identify the source files.) Then you just need to imitate the structure and deploy based on this structure.

'Deploy' operation is just a upload operation, so you just needs to upload the files in specific structure, then azure can identify it.

Finally, you can use zip deploy to deploy your function app(Or to say deploy a project, a structure that azure can run must first run success on local.).

`az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src clouddrive/<filename>.zip`

(Above command is been used by some Integrated Development Environment, such as Visual Studio.)

I suggest you to use the first way, because it is simpler.

Comment: my programming language is nodejs. I used Visual Studio code to deploy, but when I deployed the project, All functions are deployed into one Azure function app. while I wanted to deploy each function to a separate Azure function app. Does it make sense?

Comment: @MasoudJahromi To be honest, it looks like your approach is a bit redundant. . . Unless you have special needs, there is no need to deploy them separately. Do you have special requirements that you must deploy separately?

Comment: @MasoudJahromi What you see is expected. The general structure of azure function is that there are multiple functions (or to say triggers) in a function app. This can also avoid some troubles in environment configuration.

Comment: @MasoudJahromi But if you want to do it, then separate deployment is also possible (I have written the specific steps in my answer)

Comment: It may be that what @MasoudJahromi is after here is the ability to deploy functions atomically rather than being required to deploy all functions that are part of a function app. This deployment model is to be lauded, as the creation and deployment of new (tiny) microservices becomes very fast and independent of other microservices. Based on my research there is not a clean way to deploy individual functions to a function app, and the atomic deployment model would require a separate project, pipeline and function app for each one. That, in my opinion, is way too much overhead to be valuable.